# How to pass a custom post ID through WooCommerce add to cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom post type that works as a product. How can I pass the post ID through add to cart in WooCommerce?

I would like to change the status of the post only when the user has bought the specific product.

```
//Store the custom field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_custom_data_vase', 1, 2 );

function add_cart_item_custom_data_vase( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    global $post;

    $cart_item_meta['card_id'] = (string)$post->post_name;

    return $cart_item_meta; 
}
```

Comment: When the visitor adding the product to the cart doesn't mean its bought. Please update the question to make your query more clear.

Comment: after i have the id i firing action on woocommerce_thankyou

Comment: @AttentionCreative You could include an input hidden field with this post ID inside the add to cart form… then you will be able to get it in the hooked  function from your question code using something  like `if ( isset($_POST['custom_pos_id'])) { $post_id = $_POST['custom_pos_id']; }`